# Create a new dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dropdown after I choose an option in an original dropdown.

This is the HTML code:

```
<br>
<select id ="select-container" onchange="addSelect('select-container');">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
</select>
<br>
```

This is the javascript.

```
function categorygenerate() {
    //for testing purposes
    var categoryarray = new Array(),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        categoryarray[i] = Math.random();
    }
    return categoryarray;
}

function addSelect(divname) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var html = '<select>',
        dates = categorygenerate(),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        html += "<option value='" + dates[i] + "'>" + dates[i] + "</option>";
    }
    html += '</select>';
    newDiv.innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log($("#" + divname).html());
    console.log(newDiv);
}
```

The debugger mode shows me no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are trying to append your code in the "original select": look at the `id` of your `select`.

You have to add a `div` tag with the `id="select-container"` and remove it from the "original select"

Here is a working snippet:

```js
function categorygenerate() {
    //for testing purposes
    var categoryarray = new Array(),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        categoryarray[i] = Math.random();
    }
    return categoryarray;
}

function addSelect(divname) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var html = '<select>',
        dates = categorygenerate(),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        html += "<option value='" + dates[i] + "'>" + dates[i] + "</option>";
    }
    html += '</select>';
    newDiv.innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log($("#" + divname).html());
    console.log(newDiv);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<select onchange="addSelect('select-container');">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="select-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your select in a div with the id `select-container`. Ofcourse, give your select an other ID. Then your code should work. It's because you try to append a new `select` to the original one in your HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/b248a4k1/